# Sphinx Configuring Multiple Sources

Tags: php, search-engine, sphinx

We have a modular site and would like to setup searching by module.

For example, we have modules: news, customers, inventory

So if the user is on the news module and they do a search, the results should only be from the news table.

I've been reading Sphinx documentation but haven't seen if this is possible or not.

We are using PHP and from the [Sphinx PHP API](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs), there does not seem to be a method to set the source.

Can this be done?  What would an example conf file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have three sources, assuming you have three tables, right? Then you will have 3 indexes created, you can select which index to use when executing the **query** method

```
$sphinx->query ($query, $index);
```